# Codepen is not displaying my custom cursor via URL

Tags: css, cursor, codepen

I've tried to find the solution to this. My source images are hosted by github, and my code seems consistent with all the documentation.

Here is a stripped-down version of the pen: *[redacted]*

Problem code:

```
.opacity-layer:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 10000px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  cursor: crosshair;
  cursor: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zimaben/AcmeProject/master/images/pointer.png), auto;
}
```

The Cursor image on hover is neither displaying or throwing errors for me. Is this a CodePen issue?

Comment: i did not understand

Comment: Cursor image is not displaying

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, leaving the question up in case other people run into this. The image in question was just over the dimension limit the browser accepts for cursor images. Documentation is spotty and varies between browsers but here is the documentation link that solved it for me:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property